# Как получить imap письмо в киррилической кодировке?

Tags: python, python-3.x, кодировка, email, imap

У нас есть такой код:

```
import imaplib
import email


mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
mail.login('frozenace1305@gmail.com', 'loveyou4evet')
mail.list()
mail.select("inbox")
result, data = mail.search(None, "ALL")

ids = data[0]
id_list = ids.split()
latest_email_id = id_list[-1]

result, data = mail.fetch(latest_email_id, "(RFC822)")
raw_email = data[0][1]
mail = email.message_from_bytes(raw_email)
subject = mail.get('Subject')
h = email.header.decode_header(subject)
print(h)
```

Получаем такой результат:

```
[(b'INTUIT.ru: \xd0\x9f\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb2\xd1\x8b\xd1\x88\xd0\xb5\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb5 \xd0\xba\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbb\xd0\xb8\xd1\x84\xd0\xb8\xd0\xba\xd0\xb0\xd1\x86\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb8 \xd0\xbf\xd0\xbe \xd0\xbf\xd1\x80\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb3\xd1\x80\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbc\xd0\xbc\xd0\xb5 \xd0\xb8\xd0\xbd\xd1\x84\xd0\xbe\xd1\x80\xd0\xbc\xd0\xb0\xd1\x86\xd0\xb8\xd0\xbe\xd0\xbd\xd0\xbd\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb9 \xd0\xb1\xd0\xb5\xd0\xb7\xd0\xbe\xd0\xbf\xd0\xb0\xd1\x81\xd0\xbd\xd0\xbe\xd1\x81\xd1\x82\xd0\xb8 \xd1\x81\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb3\xd0\xbb\xd0\xb0\xd1\x81\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb0 \xd1\x81 \xd0\xa4\xd0\xa1\xd0\xa2\xd0\xad\xd0\x9a \xd0\xa0\xd0\xbe\xd1\x81\xd1\x81\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb8', 'utf-8')]
```

Как превратить его в кириллицу?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
encoded_title, encoding = h[0]
decoded_title = encoded_title.decode(encoding)
```

Comment: Спасибо большое. А что в Вашем примере title? Если это encoded_title, то получаем ошибку:
    decoded_title = encoded_title.decode(encoding)
    AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'

Comment: Странно, потому что в вашем выводе видно, что первый элемент - это не `str`.

Comment: Спасибо большое, все заработало. Новое сообщение пришло и там не надо было ничего декодировать.

Comment: А как для  body такое заюзать?