# Ошибка 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc7

Tags: python

Получаю список почтовых сообщений с помощью `imaplib`. У меня на `Windows 10` все работает. На сервере `Ubuntu` и там эта ошибка

```
print("Connecting to {}...".format(server))
imap = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(server)
print("Connected! Logging in as {}...".format(login));
imap.login(login, password)
print("Logged in! Listing messages...");
status, select_data = imap.select('INBOX')
nmessages = select_data[0].decode('utf-8')
status, search_data = imap.search(None, 'ALL')
for msg_id in search_data[0].split():

status, msg_data = imap.fetch(msg_id, '(RFC822)')
msg_raw = msg_data[0][1].decode("utf8")
```

Ругается на последнюю строчку. Кодировка файла `UTF-8`. Добавил в заголовок хешбенг.  Все равно ругается.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-
```

Comment: Значит кодировка файла данных не utf-8

Comment: @insolor ну так на винде работает

Comment: Нельзя полагаться что всегда будет utf-8, нужно определять кодировку из письма. Посмотрите вот этот вопрос и ответ: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/743733/python-imap-получить-письмо-в-киррилической-кодировке

Comment: Кстати, какая версия python? `#!/usr/bin/env python` на Ubuntu запустит с помощью python 2

Comment: @insolor а как указать 3,6?

Comment: `#!/usr/bin/env python3` укажите просто

Comment: @insolor всё равно не пашет

Comment: Что конкретно не пашет? Сделали определение кодировки?

Comment: @insolor https://pastebin.com/j1YU3NaX

Comment: Смотрели вопрос, на который я ссылку дал?

Comment: @insolor там для темы, с темой у меня тут тоже проблем нет) вопрос с телом письма

Comment: Скорее всего кодировка одинаковая для заголовка и для тела.

Comment: для темы я не указываю принудительно кодировку, оно по дефолту корректное. А для тела мне приходится его в utf-8  приводить, так как там крякозябры

Comment: Добавьте весь код из pastebin в вопрос, и покажите содержимое `msg_data[0][1]`

Comment: @insolor спасибо за ответ, нашёл проблему. а именно в https://stackoverflow.com/a/21214385/1088259

Comment: @insolor почему то оно выбрасывает эту самую ошибку когда запускается в этом кроне